# Can mutt automatically sign emails that it encrypts?

Tags: mutt, gpg, pgp

I love the mutt option `crypt_opportunistic_encrypt`. This allows me to automatically encrypt emails to recipients for whom I have the key. (And not if I cc to a group that contains members without keys.)

However, I'd also like to automatically sign emails that I encrypt. IMO, if a recipient doesn't use PGP generally, I wouldn't encrypt, and signing would just be noise to them. However, if they *do* use PGP generally, I'd encrypt and sign by default. Is there a way to do this in mutt?

I looked at `crypt_autosign`, which signs to all, and `crypt_replysign` and `crypt_replysignencrypted`, which only deal with replied emails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution I found is:

```
send-hook . 'reset pgp_autoencrypt'
send-hook "!~l ~t onemail@example\\.org" "set crypt_autoencrypt crypt_autosign"
```

to automatically encrypt messages to specific recipients, where `!~l` pattern is to not activate encryption if the mail is also addressed to a known mailing list, and `~t addr` means "To: addr".

Note that `send-hook` is matched against all messages: new and replies.

Some references:

- https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/UseGPG
- https://dev.mutt.org/doc/manual.html#send-hook

Comment: I used to do something similar, but (as hinted in the question) the [problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235328/how-can-i-gpg-encrypt-for-only-a-sole-specific-recipient-in-mutt) is that it works poorly for emails to multiple recipients. If you have a key for only one recipient, mutt will still try to encrypt (and sign) to all. `crypt_opportunistic_encrypt` avoids this problem, by not encrypting in this case.